# push_back vs emplace vs insert in vector in C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Strange behavior of copy constructor for `push_back`, `emplace` and `insert`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
   private:
   int *big;
   public:
   void make_null() 
   { 
      delete [] big;
      big = NULL;
      cout<<"Made NULL\n";
   }
   void show() { cout<<"Memory Allocated\n"; }
   Test ()
   {
      big = new int[10000];
      cout<<"Default Constructor gets called \n";
   }
   Test( const Test &a)
   {
      big = new int[10000];
      int k;
      for(k = 0; k < 10000 ; k++)
         big[k] = a.big[k];  
      cout<<"Copy Constructor gets called \n";
   }
   Test & operator = ( const Test &a)
   {
      if(this != &a)
      {
         delete [] big;
         if(a.big)
         {
           big = new int[10000];
           int k;
           for(k = 0; k < 10000 ; k++)
              big[k] = a.big[k];  
           cout<<"New memory gets allocated \n";
         }
         else
         {
           big = NULL;
           cout<<"NULL value gets assigned \n";
         }
      }
      else
         cout<<"Same pointer assignment\n";      
      cout<<"Assignment operator gets called \n";
        return *this;
   }
    ~Test ()
   {
      delete [] big;
      cout<<"Destructor gets called \n";
   }
};
int main()
{
   Test tObj;
   vector<Test> tVec;
   tVec.push_back(tObj);
   tVec[0].show();
   cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
   Test rObj;
   tVec.emplace(tVec.end(),rObj);
   tVec[1].show();
   cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
   Test qObj;
   tVec.insert(tVec.end(),qObj);
   tVec[2].show();
   cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
   Test sObj;
   vector<Test> sVec;
   sVec.push_back(sObj);
   sVec[0].show();
   cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
   tVec[0] = tVec[0];
   tVec[0] = sVec[0];
   sVec[0].make_null();
   tVec[1] = sVec[0];
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Default Constructor gets called 
Copy Constructor gets called 
Memory Allocated
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Default Constructor gets called 
Copy Constructor gets called 
Copy Constructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Memory Allocated
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Default Constructor gets called 
Copy Constructor gets called 
Copy Constructor gets called 
Copy Constructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Memory Allocated
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Default Constructor gets called 
Copy Constructor gets called 
Memory Allocated
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Same pointer assignment
Assignment operator gets called 
New memory gets allocated 
Assignment operator gets called 
Made NULL
NULL value gets assigned 
Assignment operator gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Destructor gets called 
Destructor gets called
```

The `push_back` calls copy constructor once, while `emplace` calls it twice,
and `insert` calls it thrice.
I am not able to figure out what is the reason behind that.

Comment: Reallocation of previous elements.

Comment: do you really need this wall of code to see how often a copy constructor is called? Please make it more minimal. And btw you forgot to ask a question ;)

Comment: Question was why copy constructor was called more than once in case of insert and emplace , and second when I was using insert or emplace for first element insertion instead of push back the copy constructor has been called only once .(tobi303)  Sorry for the huge code . Kindly exclude the unnecessary part . (LogicStuff) Sorry I am not getting your answer could you please elaborate in detail .

Comment: Also note that with `emplace` you pass arguments to construct the type that is in the vector and it creates that object in the vector with those arguments.  This is useful as you do not have to create an object to add things into the vector.

Answer (score 0):

In the main function and after this line:

```
vector<Test> tVec;
```

just add this:

```
tVec.reserve(N); // N is the number of items you think that you are going to add to the vector
```

Your problem will disappear.

**Why?**

When adding elements to `std::vector` (push, emplace or insert), a reallocation may be happened. Reallocation will cause copying all the items to a new place of the memory (heap). Copying elements will defiantly call the copy constructor and then call the destructor for the old items.

`tVec.reserve(N);` will reserve a contiguous memory blocks. this will prevent the reallocation (or in better words it will not be needed) until the count of the pushed elements is less than `N`.

Comment: Please **don't just** reserve 99999 elements for a simple test program. Add a few more numbers and a new problem will appear. Reserving a reasonable amount is ok, but reserving 99999 elements for, imagine, a hello world program would be a bit too much, no?

Comment: sure sure. This is not a real world code. Anyway you are right I am going to edit. Thanks